# ToTraceString takes long time to execute

Tags: performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a service that executes a query through Entity Framework 4, and it doesn't have any problem, until now I tried to execute it on a Windows Server 2003 with IIS 6 or a Windows 7 with IIS 7.

Now, when I try to run the same service on a Windows Server 2008 R2 and IIS 7.5 the **same query** becomes very slow (From like 200ms to 3 seconds). Analyzing the problem I discovered that takes so long when it tries to generate the sql query to execute, just calling a **ToTraceString() take almost 3 seconds.**

I don't know if the OS and IIS version could be the problem, but they are the only differences I see.

Thank you

**Update**

I have found out that problem is effectively in the time that Entity Framework takes to generate the query, and it depends about the processor, with Intel it works very well, **with AMD it is much slower and it gets worse if the application runs with multi-cores**, forcing the w3wp to use a single core it get better but still slower than the Intel solution

Comment: I recommended to use Compile Queries ! May It will help to reduce conversion time ! (Note: If you are using Code First Approach than it will not help

Comment: Just a suggestion: you can also assign a delegate to `Database.Log` to capture and log all queries. If you want to use it for one query then just set it before execution and unset it after.